# PHP Gallery not correctly displaying first two images in gallery

Tags: javascript, php, gallery

For whatever reason, the first two images in every gallery that I have on my site are not being correctly displayed. I have looked in the page source and found this:

```
<td><a href="javascript:imgSubmit('image.php?gallery=053&imgnum=1');"><img src="/galleries/053/thumbs/." class="thumb_img" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:imgSubmit('image.php?gallery=053&imgnum=2');"><img src="/galleries/053/thumbs/.." class="thumb_img" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:imgSubmit('image.php?gallery=053&imgnum=3');"><img src="/galleries/053/thumbs/053img009.jpg" class="thumb_img" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:imgSubmit('image.php?gallery=053&imgnum=4');"><img src="/galleries/053/thumbs/053img008.jpg" class="thumb_img" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:imgSubmit('image.php?gallery=053&imgnum=5');"><img src="/galleries/053/thumbs/053img011.jpg" class="thumb_img" border="0" /></a></td>
```

I'm guessing its something in the initialisation of the FOR loop but I am not seeing here, but its clearly wrong for the first two images. Here is the relevant code in the script.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

require("config.php");
require("common.php");

$gallery    = $_GET['page'];
$gallerydir = DOC_ROOT . GALLERY_ROOT . '/' . $gallery;
$imglist    = getImageList($gallerydir);
$imgcnt     = count($imglist);

$currpage   = (isset($_GET['currpage'])) 
    ? (int) $_GET['currpage'] 
    : 1;

// get page elements 
$js          = getJavaScript($imglist);
$thumb_table = getThumbTableHTML($gallery, $imglist, $imgcnt, $currpage);
$image_cnt   = getImageRangeHTML($imgcnt, $currpage);
$page_nav    = getPageNavHTML($imgcnt, $currpage, $gallery);

// load template header and body 
$head = file_get_contents("./template/header.html");
$body = file_get_contents("./template/thumb_page.html");

// insert page elements 
$head = str_replace('<-- JAVASCRIPT -->', $js, $head);
$body = str_replace('<-- THUMBNAIL_TABLE -->', $thumb_table, $body);
$body = str_replace('<-- IMAGE_COUNT -->', $image_cnt, $body);
$body = str_replace('<-- PAGE_NAVIGATION -->', $page_nav, $body);

// output
echo $head;
echo $body;
//********************************************************************* 
// Begin thumbnail page related functions 
//*********************************************************************

function getImageRangeHTML($imgcnt, $currpage) {

    $max_per_page = TABLE_COLS * TABLE_ROWS;
    $pagecnt      = getThumbPageCount($imgcnt); 
    $first_image  = ($currpage - 1) * $max_per_page + 1;
    $last_image   = ($currpage == $pagecnt) 
        ? $imgcnt 
        : $currpage * $max_per_page;

    $str = "
        <font size=\"2\" face=\"Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif\"><i>
        $imgcnt images
        </i></font>
    ";

    return $str;
}
//********************************************************************* 

function getPageNavHTML($imgcnt, $currpage, $gallery) {

    $pagecnt  = getThumbPageCount($imgcnt); 
    $self     = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    // only proceed if there is more than 1 page of thumbs
    if ($pagecnt == 1) { return; }

    $str = "<ul>\n";

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecnt; $i++) {

        if ($i == $currpage) {
            $str .= "<li class=\"active\">$i</li>";
        } else {
            $str .= "<li><a href=\"javascript:imgSubmit('$self?";
            $str .= "gallery=$gallery&currpage=$i');\">$i</a></li>";
        }
    }

    $str .= "</ul>\n";
    return $str;
}

//******************************************************************** 

function getThumbTableHTML($gallery, $imglist, $imgcnt, $currpage) {
    $max_per_page = TABLE_COLS * TABLE_ROWS;

    // set index of page's first image in image list array
    $first_image_index = ($currpage - 1) * $max_per_page;

    // set index of page's last image in image list array 
    $last_image_index = ($imgcnt < $currpage * $max_per_page)
        ? $last_image_index = $imgcnt
        : $currpage * $max_per_page;

    $str = '<table border="0" id="thumb_table">' . "\n";

    // loop control var
    $column_cnt  = 1;

    // loop through current page images
    for ($i = $first_image_index; $i < $last_image_index; $i++) {
        # build path to thumb
        $thumburl  = GALLERY_ROOT . "/$gallery/thumbs/" . $imglist[$i];

        // insert row tag if this is the first column
        if ($column_cnt == 1) { $str .= "<tr>\n"; }

        // insert thumbnail, and surrounding html
        $str .= "<td>";
        $str .= "<a href=\"javascript:imgSubmit('image.php?gallery=$gallery";
        $str .= "&imgnum=" . ($i + 1) . "');\">";
        $str .= "<img src=\"$thumburl\" class=\"thumb_img\" ";
        $str .= "border=\"0\" /></a>";
        $str .= "</td>\n";

        if ($column_cnt == TABLE_COLS) {
            $str .= "</tr>\n\n";
            $column_cnt = 1;
        } else {
            $column_cnt++;
        }
    }

    $str .= "</table>\n";
    return $str;
}

// ********************************************************************* 

function getThumbPageCount($imgcnt) {

    $page_cnt = (int) (($imgcnt - 1) / (TABLE_COLS * TABLE_ROWS)) + 1;
    return $page_cnt;
}

// ********************************************************************* 
?>
```

Here is the relevant code for the GetImageList() function

```
    function getImageList($gallerydir) {
        if (isset($_POST['imglist'])) {
            $imglist = $_POST['imglist'];
        } else {
            $fh = opendir("$gallerydir/thumbs");

            // read directory, and loop through retreived filenames
            while ($file = readdir($fh)) {
                // if image, add filename to image list 
                if (!preg_match("\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg|jpe)$", $file)) {
                    $imglist[] = $file; 
                }
            }
            closedir($fh);
        }

        if (is_array($imglist)) {
            ksort($imglist);
        } else {
            $imglist = false;
        }
        return $imglist;
    }

//*********************************************************************
// Javascript writes image list as http posted array

function getJavaScript($imglist) {
    $str = '
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function imgSubmit(s) {
        document.img.method = "post";
        document.img.action = s;
        document.img.submit();
    }

    function imgList() {
    ';
    $str .= "\tvar imglist = new Array('" . implode("', '", $imglist) . "');\n";
    $str .= '
        for (var i=0; i < imglist.length; i++) {
            document.write ("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"imglist[]\" ");
            document.write ("value=\"" + imglist[i] + "\" />"); 
        }
    }
    </script>
    ';
    return $str;
}

//*********************************************************************

?>
```

Comment: You’re listing the contents of a directory somewhere and that contains also entries `.` and `..` so you’ll have to filter those out

Comment: It's probably your `getImageList()` method that doesn't filter out the current (`.`) and parent (`..`) directory

Comment: I've added the getImageList() function code to my question.

Comment: Thank you for the edits. I really appreciate it. Unfortunately it has yet to solve the problem. One thing I discovered was that all of the images available to the gallery are still being posted, the two pictures that don't work do not even exist and are addons to the total amount of images. Is it something in the for loop maybe?